# RetryPolicy mechanism for SQL Azure Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, azure-sql-database

I'm using `TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy`. I would like to know if the Retry policy is enough for only connecting the Entity framework. Once the entities are connected, I will be using entities in multiple places. In between opening the connection and using the connection, what happens if the connection is lost? Will the Retry policy take care of the connection?

**Connection class**

```
static class Azure
{
    static RetryPolicy policy = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy>  (5,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    public static CrmEfEntities ConnectCustomerEntity()
    {
        CrmEfEntities customerEntity = null;
        policy.ExecuteAction(() =>
        { 
            customerEntity = new Entities(ConnectionStringCustomerDB());
            string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION       Customer_Test_Federation(TestId =" + testId + ") WITH RESET, FILTERING=ON";
            customerEntity.Connection.Open();
            customerEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand(federationCmdText);                  
        });  
        return customerEntity;
    }
}
```

I am calling the above method in the controller like here:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{      
    private static readonly CrmEfEntities _db = Azure.ConnectCustomerEntity();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        var employeeList = GetEmployeeDetails().ToList();            
        return View(employeeList);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        var employee= from emp in _db.Employees
        from coun in _db.Countries
        where emp.CountryId == coun.Id
        select new CompanyDetailsModel
        {
            Id = emp.Id,   
            Name = emp.Name,                                           
            countryName=coun.Name
        };
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your English is terrible, I don't understand the question. Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: Leon, Sorry for that, I corrected the grammer